# How to recolor an existing canvas element using Javascript, JQuery and/or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

Fangraph recently switched from displaying heatmaps in a table, to displaying them in a canvas element. When the heatmap was in table format, I was recoloring it by iterating through each td, like this:

```
$('.coloredElement').each(function(){
    var number = +($(this).text());
    if(number > 0.099) {
        $(this).parent("td").css({"background-color": "niceColor", "color":"awesomeColor"});
    } else if (number > 0.089) {
        $(this).parent("td").css({"background-color": "anotherColor", "color":"yetAnotherColor"});
    } else if (...etc) { 
        ...etc
    }
});
```

This is an example of [the new heatmap format](http://www.fangraphs.com/zonegrid.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF&ss=2017-01-01&se=2017-12-01&type=4&hand=all&count=all&blur=1&grid=10&view=bat&pitch=&season=2017&data=pi) in which a canvas element is apparently colored with a script:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gridCanvas");                                         
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");                                         
ctx.fillStyle="#fff"; ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,675);                                        
ctx.fillStyle="#000"; ctx.font = "15px Arial";                
ctx.fillText("Mike Trout AVG/P vs All Pitchers", 5, 20);                
ctx.fillText("Season: 2017-04-03 to 2017-10-01", 5, 40);                
ctx.fillText("Count: All Counts | Total Pitches: 2597 | View: Catcher", 5, 60);         
ctx.fillStyle="#0000FF";     
etc...
```

Is it possible to to recolor `ctx.fillStyle` based on `ctx.fillText`, using plain javascript, or jQuery?  `ctx.fillText` for the relevant parts of the canvas is in the format `ctx.fillText(".062",270,220)`, with the string ".062" (representing the player's average in that part of the strike zone), being the part I would base the color on.

Alternatively is it possible to address the issue with PHP? It ocurred to me that if I retrieve each script along with its corresponding heatmap, it might be possible to replace each instance of (for example) blue with something else, programmatically. To this end I used [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), parsing out the script and setting it's inner text to a variable (`canvas_script`). I've tried using both `str_replace` and `preg_replace` to change the colors in the string contained by the variable, but I must be making a mistake, because when I echo out the resulting `canvas_script`, the original colors remain unchanged. This was what I tried using PHP:

```
include_once('../SHD/simple_html_dom.php');
$url       = "pathToHeatmap";
$context    = stream_context_create();  
stream_context_set_params($context, array('user_agent' => 'my_identity_location_and_purpose'));
$html       = file_get_html($url, 0, $context);
if($html) {
    foreach($html->find('#gridCanvas') as $heat) {
        echo '<div style="text-align: center;">' . $heat . '</div>'; // center map on page
    }

    $s = 1; // increment this variable to loop through script elements in DOM
    foreach($html->find('#content > script') as $script) {
        if($s === 9) { 
            $canvas_script_raw = $script->innertext; 
            $canvas_script     = str_replace("#0000ff", "#4F261B", $canvas_script_raw); // tried to replace blue with something else
            $canvas_script     = preg_replace('/#0000ff/', '#4F261B', $canvas_script_raw); // tried a different method
        }
        $s++;
    }
} else {
    // if the request fails print error message
}
```

I also looked into using [Gradientmaps.js](https://github.com/jessegavin/gradientmaps), which seems to recolor an image based on light and dark values, after converting it to greyscale. However as the average per pitch numbers (`ctx.fillText`) go up, the value of their corresponding color doesn't necesarily go up, so I can't make a satisfactory gradient.

Comment: how is writing the Javascript code to draw that heatmap on the canvas??

Comment: @spankajd  I don't know exactly how Fangraph generates their Javascript for each heat map, but there are over a thousand players, so it must be an automated process based on MLB data.